Why is the `retrospective_penalty` not included in the SmacPlannerHybrid::dynamicParametersCallback method?
When writing a pipeline that sets planner server parameters at runtime I realized that the retrospective_penalty cannot really be changed at runtime. For example I could set the penalty with ros2 param set /planner_server GridBased.retrospective_penalty 0.3 and ros2 param get ... would return 0.3, but the planner server still planned with whatever value for the penalty I wrote in the parameter yaml file.
I did some digging and saw runtime configuration was enabled with this PR before retro_penalty came about. Then checking the current nav2 repo rolling branch, the retro_penalty is included in the SmacPlannerHybrid::configure while it is not included in the SmacPlannerHybrid::dynamicParametersCallback method.
My question is: is the ability to set retro_penalty at runtime disabled by design or was the parameter unintentionally left out from dynamicParametersCallback when it came about?
